# Asynchrouns CellTree displaying loading icon GWT

Tags: gwt

how can I display a loading icon, when the data is not yet avalible vor the leave of the celltree.
To get the data for each leave, a AsyncDataProvider is used, which makes a network request. As long as he is not returned, a loading message should be displayed. Is there a way to do this?

Regards,
Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. **The celltree has functionality to display a loading state, when the RowCount doesn't match the DataCount available**. So, if the data isn't present yet, you just sent the `RowCount(1, true);` which tells the tree, that it has exactly one element, which isn't here yet.

This makes the tree displaying the loading sign:

[image]

Comment: I cannot find any method RowCount. Could you please post the JavaDoc Link?

Answer (score 0):

The following is a rather generic solution, but one I find very useful. It displays a 'busy' mouse pointer whenever an RPC call is in progress. You can adapt it to your needs. I define a class as follows:

```
class CallWrapper<T> implements AsyncCallback<T> {
AsyncCallback<T> callback;

public CallWrapper(AsyncCallback<T> cb) {
    callback = cb;
    DOM.setStyleAttribute(RootPanel.getBodyElement(), "cursor", "wait");
}

public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {       
    DOM.setStyleAttribute(RootPanel.getBodyElement(), "cursor", "default");
    callback.onFailure(caught);
}

public void onSuccess(T result) {       
    DOM.setStyleAttribute(RootPanel.getBodyElement(), "cursor", "default");
    callback.onSuccess(result);
}
}
```

Then you can wrap each individual AsyncCallback as follows:

```
public void callService(AsyncCallback<String> callback) {
myRPC.doStuff(new CallWrapper<String>(callback));
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: would, but I don't like to display a loading state for the whole page, when only a small part is updating. I posted my solution above